# How to block stderr output in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, stderr

I am running a Python script in Jupyter Notebook and a library I am using (PyNN), produces a lot of stderr output that slows down the code and fills up the memory. I have tried using %%capture at the beginning of the cell but nothing has changed, and the output remains the same.

I am posting a snap of the output.[image]

Any tips are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the parameter --no-stderr with the capture ?

Comment: Try ```ipython notebook --quiet``` (this disables logging) in addition to @edubriguenti suggestion.

Comment: @edubriguenti I tried but %%capture doesn't seem to work at all for me right now

Comment: @AvivYaniv If I understand correctly this one should be run in a terminal of the notebook, but I got ImportError: No module named notebook.notebookapp

Comment: @costisst Allright try ```jupyter notebook notebook.ipynb --log-level=0```

Answer (score 2):

If the issue is with printing, you can redirect the stream with `contextlib`:

```
import contextlib
import os

devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
contextlib.redirect_stderr(devnull)
```

Comment: I am having for than 1 scripts in my code, which implement different classes. I tried this code in the main script, which is the only one using the PyNN library, but it didn't work. I also tried adding it in every script and it didn't work either

Comment: Bonus tip: If you want to temporarily redirect the output (e.g. for just one fucntion call) you can use it as a context manager: `with redirect_stdout(open(os.devnull,'w')):`. Works for stderr and stdout.

Comment: Does that actually close the devnull handle @mad

Comment: You may need multiple handlers as such: `with open(os.devnull, 'w') as h, redirect_stdout(h):` to properly close the contexts.

Comment: @Maximilian-Burszley: Good observation. I'm not sure if this is the right way to check whether the handler is closed, but I used `psutil.Process().open_files()` and saw nothing. I also tried it with an actual file inside `open()` instead of `os.devnull`, same result. So it appears to me that the file handler is indeed properly closed with the nested `open()`.

Comment: This is not working for me: still tons of stderr spewage

Answer (score 0):

I use css to workaround:

```
%%html
<style>
    div.output_stderr {
    display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: how do you apply this to the notebook?